# Teradata equivalent of persisted computed column (in SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, calculated-columns, teradata

We have a few tables with persisted computed columns in SQL Server.

Is there an equivalent of this in Teradata?  And, if so, what is the syntax and are there any limitations?

The particular computed columns I am looking at conform some account numbers by removing leading zeros - an index is also created on this conformed account number:

```
ACCT_NUM_std AS ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(39),
                               SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM([ACCT_NUM])),
                                         PATINDEX('%[^0]%',
                                                  LTRIM(RTRIM([ACCT_NUM])) + '.'
                                                 ),
                                         LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM([ACCT_NUM])))
                                        )
                              ),
                       ''
                      ) PERSISTED
```

With the Teradata TRIM function, the trimming part would be a little simpler:

```
ACCT_NUM_std AS COALESCE(CAST(TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM TRIM(BOTH FROM ACCT_NUM))) AS varchar(39)),
                         ''
                        )
```

I guess I could just make this a normal column and put the code to standardize the account numbers in all the processes which insert into the table.  We did this to put the standardization code in one place.

Comment: I'm guessing that there is a reason why you can't create a view with the 'computed data' and source from that?

Comment: @bogertron it really needs to be indexed because some things need to join on the standardized account number and some things don't.

Comment: That is a good reason :). Yeah, Teradata does not support this type of mechanism. The next best option, i guess would be to create triggers or do what you did (recreate logic). Nothing elegant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have been able to determine, Teradata does not support computed columns in tables.

I adopted the strategy of having all the various inserts use the same code, which has resulted in code duplication, unfortunately.